# Java inputStream as object property, close HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, struts2, struts, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I have an inputStream from an HttpURLConnection. The inputStream is passed as property to an object that will later be called via its getter from the Struts2 framework to provide the stream directly to the users browser. Although the code seems to work as expected I am worried that I cannot close properly the HttpURLConnection as this will invalidate my input stream before is read from the user's browser. The code is as follows:

```
private void DownloadOutput(DownloadableObject retVal, URL u, String cookie) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);

            Map<String, List<String>> headers =  conn.getHeaderFields();

            retVal.setContentLength(conn.getContentLength());
            retVal.setStream(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()));
//          in.close();
//            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is there any suggestion as what would be the optimal approach? I assume that the gc will later on clear the HttpURLConnection object but it is good to do some housekeeping pro-actively. I also assume that the "new BufferedInputStream" passed into the proxy object will be closed by the underlying  struts framework(?).

Answer (score 1):

convert it to string and then set it to an object

[Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string)

Streams basically represents a handle input/output source, and when you close the reference it loses the handle

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Comment: Cannot do this as the stream may represent a pdf of several hundred pages. Providing that this is on a web application, it won't go down well to consume so much memory if a few users request the wrong pdf.

Comment: @janagn in that case, you need to create a local file out of it, and then save the reference to that local file stream in your object. HTTPConnectionURL would close the stream as soon as close() method is being called.

Comment: Unless, if this is ok NOT to close it as the code shows. Is this acceptable as a "best practise"?

Comment: @janagn No, you should always close HttpURLConnection since otherwise you are simply blocking/keeping the port busy for no real benefit whatsoever

Comment: OK then my problem becomes more complicated. In essence I need to notify my object to close the connection once the stream has been read from the struts framework.

Comment: @janagn Didn't understood your point. I am only suggesting you to close the connection object as you would normally do, and create a different file (fileInputStream) for your proxy

Comment: Maybe a sync/communication misunderstanding. My problem is that I cannot save the input stream as a file and I cannot create byte[] in memory. So as I said in my answer the solution was to override the close() of the stream and call the conn.disconnect in there when the struts framework called the stream.close.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the cleaner way is to subclass the inputstream and Override the close. That way when struts will call the close, after having read the stream, you can close your connection:

```
private class mytest extends  BufferedInputStream {

        private HttpURLConnection aConn;

        public mytest(HttpURLConnection conn, InputStream in) {
            super(in);
            this.aConn = conn;
        }

        public mytest(HttpURLConnection conn, InputStream in, int size) {
            super(in, size);
            this.aConn = conn;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            System.out.println("The stream has been closed, time to close the connection");
            aConn.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Connection has been disconnected");
        }
    }
```

So the above object is the stream that will be set in the action as the inputStream parameter.